# ¿Cómo guardar datos usando un metodo de otro controlador?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

necesito una auyda, estoy haciendo un método que calcula las piezas vendidas de un producto en un controlador llamado Venta, y hace el guardado en una tabla llamada salida usando otro metodo que llamo venderpieza que se encuentra en orto controlador que llamo Salidas. una venta es de un solo producto ( sin importar la cantidad ), ejemplo, la venta numero 2 es de una patineta pero son 10 patinetas.yo optengo el registro de las piezas vendidas en cada producto, pero cuando quiero usar mi otro metodo que realiza mi guardado en bdd pierdo la idea y no me piedo en la tarea, aquí les dejo mi código , acoto que este metodo es booleano y solo guarda cuando todo es verdadero.

metodo que estoy creando

```
 public bool VenderPiezas (int Id_Venta , int Id_Producto , int Cantidad_venta)
    {
        var producto = db.Producto.Where(n => n.Id_Producto == Id_Producto).FirstOrDefault();//un producto
        var venta = db.Venta.Where(n => n.Id_Venta == Id_Venta).FirstOrDefault();//una venta

       var piezas = db.Tiene.Where(n => n.Id_Producto == Id_Producto).Select(m => m.Id_Pieza).ToList(); //cantidad de producto
        var tienes = db.Tiene.Where(n => n.Id_Producto == Id_Producto).Select(m=>m.Id_Tiene).ToList();
       // var cantidades = db.Producto.Where(n => n.Id_Producto == Id_Producto).Select(m => m.Nombre_Producto).ToList();

        bool success = false;
        var cantidad = 0;
        if (producto != null)
        {
            var pieza = piezas;
            foreach(var tiene in tienes)
            {
                cantidad = tiene;
            }
            VenderPieza(venta.Id_Venta, pieza(esta es la variable que no me deja terminar), cantidad*Cantidad_venta); // este es el llamado al metodo que necesito usar 

        }
        return success;
    }
```

aquí dejo el otro metodo que se encuentra en controlador por si se necesita

```
 public bool VenderPieza (int Id_venta, int Id_Pieza, int Cantidad_pieza)
    {
        var pieza = db.Pieza.Where(n => n.Id_pieza == Id_Pieza);
        var venta = db.Venta.Where(n => n.Id_Venta == Id_venta).FirstOrDefault();
        var salida = db.Salida.Where(n => n.Id_Pieza == Id_Pieza).FirstOrDefault();
        var success = false;

        salida.Fecha_Salida = DateTime.Now;

        if (pieza == null)
        {
            if (venta == null)
            {
                return success;
            }
            return success;
        }
        else
        {
            salida.Cantidad_Salida = Cantidad_pieza;
            salida.Id_Pieza = Id_Pieza;
            salida.Nota_Salida = "Venta"+venta.Id_Venta.ToString();
            db.Salida.Add(salida);
            db.SaveChanges();
            success = true;
        }
        return success;
    }

}
```

Modelos

```
public class Producto
    {
        [Key]
        [Required]
        public int Id_Producto
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Código")]
    public string Codigo_Prducto //Codigo_Prducto es la referencia de como se puede buscar en el inventario.
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Nombre de producto")]
    public string Nombre_Producto //Nombre literal del producto, "celular", "bicicleta" etc.
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Descripción")]
    public string Descripcion_Producto // Caracteristicas de el producto.
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}


public class Venta
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int Id_Venta
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Required]
    public int Id_Producto
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [ForeignKey("Id_Producto")]
    public virtual Producto Producto
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Cantidad de venta")]
    public int Cantidad_Venta
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Nota")]
    public string Nota_Venta
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Cliente")]
    public string Cliente_Venta
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Fecha")]
    public DateTime Fecha_Venta
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

 public class Tiene
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int Id_Tiene
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Required]
    public int Id_Pieza
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [ForeignKey("Id_Pieza")]
    public virtual Pieza Pieza
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Required]
    public int Id_Producto
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [ForeignKey("Id_Producto")]
    public virtual Producto Producto
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Cantidad")]
    public int Cantidad_Tiene
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class Pieza
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int Id_pieza
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Nombre")]
    public string Nombre_pieza
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Costo")]
    public decimal Costo_pieza
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Código")]
    public string Codigo_pieza // campo para almacenar el código o la referencia dada por el fabricante.
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Required]
    [Display (Name = "Cantidad minima")]
    public int Cantidad_pieza
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Required]
    public string Tipo
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Unidad medida")]
    public string Unidad_medida
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Clase
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual ICollection<Producto> Productos
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

aquí es donde quiero guardar con la función que estoy llamando en el método que estoy creando

```
 public class Salida
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int Id_Salida
       {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Required]
    public int Id_Pieza
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [ForeignKey("Id_Pieza")]
    public virtual Pieza Pieza
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Cantidad de salida")]
    public int Cantidad_Salida
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Nota")]
    public string Nota_Salida
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Cliente")]
    public string Cliente_Salida
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Fecha de Salida")]
    public DateTime Fecha_Salida
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Display(Name = "Venta")]
    public virtual Venta Venta
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

muchas gracias a todos por la ayuda que me puedan brindar

Comment: Puedes agregar tu modelo de datos

Comment: son como 7 tablas, agregare las que estoy usando solamente, o las agrege todas?

Comment: Solo esas que usas en la pregunta

Comment: La verdad hay algunas cosas extrañas en la lógica así que no se si comprenderte o solo arreglar lo que veo mal.

Comment: por ejemplo la variable `pieza` que pasas al otro metodo salta un error porque no es un int como lo estas recibiendo en el parametro del metodo sino que es una lista de los id de la piezas.

Comment: todo lo que me pueda ayudar es bienvenido , es que estuve mucho tiempo sin programar y bueno me está costando agarrar otra vez el ritmo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No te deja pasar la variable porque estas asignadno una `List<>` en lugar de un `int` como espera el parametro

```
var piezas = db.Tiene.Where(n => n.Id_Producto == Id_Producto).Select(m => m.Id_Pieza).ToList();

foreach(var pieza in piezas)
{
   int result = cantidad * Cantidad_venta;
   VenderPieza(venta.Id_Venta, pieza.Id_Pieza, result);
}
```

como veras tienes una lista de `piezas` vas a tener que iterar para pasar cada `id de pieza` al otro metodo

Algunos consejos

- No llames los metodos con el mismo nombre, ambos los llamas `VenderPieza()`, aunque esten en controllers diferentes deberias ponerles algun nombre mas representativos
- Saca la funcionalidad comun en una capa de datos, o quizas en otra clase fuera del controllador, mas si esto se reutiliza en varios lugares

Algo como esto

```
public class VentasBusiness{

    public bool VentasPiezas(...){
       //codigo
    }

}

 public class Controller1{

    private VentasBusiness _ventasBusiness;

    public Controller1(){
        _ventasBusiness = new VentasBusiness();
    }

    public void Post(){
        //resto codigo
       _ventasBusiness.VentasPiezas(...);
    }
}

public class Controller2{

    private VentasBusiness _ventasBusiness;

    public Controller2(){
        _ventasBusiness = new VentasBusiness();
    }

    public void Post(){
        //resto codigo
       _ventasBusiness.VentasPiezas(...);
    }
}
```

en el ejemplo ambos controllers usan funcionalidad comun que esta en una tercera clase

Comment: aquí lo que me estas sugiriendo es crear una instancia? o estoy equivocado?

Comment: no solo crear una instancia, sino separar la funcionalidad comun fuera de los controllers